# Failed to fetch packages 404 Not Found for galera

Tags: software-installation, docker, container

I'm trying to create a galera docker image based on this dockerfile file from this link http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/docker.html

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER your name <your.user@example.org>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y  software-properties-common
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv BC19DDBA
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu trusty main'

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y galera-3 galera-arbitrator-3 mysql-wsrep-5.6 rsync

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ENTRYPOINT ["mysqld"]
```

But I get this error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can you please help me !! It used to work fine for me two weeks ago !! any idea ??

Comment: 404 means the same thing everywhere: File Not Found.  Try it yourself: Open that URL in a web browser. Then contact galeracluster.com and let them know that their documentation is out of date.

Comment: I tried that but no answer !! so I'm posting it everywhere so maybe I'll get their attention and someone will update it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository gives a "404" error, meaning it no longer exists.

http://releases.galeracluster.com/ubuntu

14.04 is quite long in the tooth and it appears they are no longer maintaining a repository for 14.04. Contact them directly or upgraded to a supported release.

For support : http://galeracluster.com/contact-us/

EDIT: deb packages for trusty can currently be found [here](http://releases.galeracluster.com/galera-3.22/ubuntu/pool/main/g/galera-3/)

Comment: I tried to contact them but i get "Failed to connect to Salesforce.com" !!

Comment: I guess you will have to find an alternate , perhaps something in the Ubuntu repositories or contact Canonical for professional support. Not sure what you want Us to do about a seemingly outdated / failed / unsupported third party product here.

Comment: the repository is there if you check http://releases.galeracluster.com/ANYPATH/ubuntu/ and I was advised to ask for an alternative here, if you can't help, thanks anyway

Comment: That link you gave 404 as well. You can try http://releases.galeracluster.com/galera-3/ubuntu/dists/ . They have release notes here - http://releases.galeracluster.com/galera-3/release-notes-galera-25.3.22.txt . The statement "Due to the peculiarities of how apt resolves packages " makes me feel the packages are not standard and / or produce conflicts. Good luck to you

Comment: they updated the dockerfile

Comment: @montatich :  \o/